# Are USB audio-adapters any good?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, sound-card

I’m running Windows XP SP3 and have an AMD CPU and on-board audio.

I don’t know what went wrong, but my sound is no longer working. I checked the volume and Control Panel settings, but everything is fine.

Now I’m planning to buy a replacement sound-card. I found some USB audio adapters which look great, but I’m wondering if it is safe to use a USB audio-adapter and if they are any good, or if should I buy normal sound-card instead.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “safe”? Are you just asking about their sound quality or are you worried about them actually damaging your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly variable depending on what you're using and the precise implementation. You might find that a 3 dollar USB dongle is good enough or that the nice expensive 'audiophile' DAC you bought is crap.

Lets start with the obvious - USB sound cards are perfectly safe. *Some* audiophiles prefer them cause they supposedly isolate the sound circuits from the main system so 'they sound better'. There's no inherent risk to a USB sound card - I've run (granted, a high quality) USB powered sound card for years and not come across any issues.

As for USB versus onboard - these days, with commodity systems having on board sound, the budget sound card is dead. Most sound cards try to offer you something beyond basic sound features. If you want a sound card to troubleshoot a usb sound card is a better choice. If you want additional features, then look at on board cards.

All that said, I'd test my *whole* sound chain - if you're using speakers, see if you can plug in a (cheap) pair of headphones to the back panel to see if thats the problem.If so, I'd try swapping cables on the speakers to rule that out too.  I'd also try a linux live cd to rule out the sound card. I'd look at the volume meter in the mixer on windows 7 or better to make sure you just don't have low volume.   Sound cards dying is kind of irregular. No point replacing your sound card, if your speakers are at fault.

If it *is* your sound card start looking at your needs, whether you are alright with the extra mess of a USB sound card, or if you can find a internal card that meets your price/requirements and you'll be on your way. The big things to look at really are outputs and inputs, if you arn't a massive audiophile. Nearly modern card will output to a single pair of speakers, and I wouldn't recommend going for something fancy if thats all you need.

Answer (score 1):

A good quality external USB audio interface works very well. I have a [Creative SoundBlaster X-Fi](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Creative-SoundBlaster-X-Fi-Go-Pro-USB-SB1290-Sound-Card-70SB129000000-/181265822854?pt=US_Sound_Card_External&hash=item2a3448f486) for one machine, and a [Logitech USB to 3.5mm adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Logitech-USB-to-3-5mm-Jack-Stereo-Headset-Audio-Adapter-External-Sound-Card-/201006651881?pt=US_Sound_Card_External&hash=item2eccee19e9) You can get generic ones for less money... In both cases these interfaces will likely be of much better quality than the onboard motherboard audio (when it was working).